# sp.if: cannot unify branches

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I am getting "sp.if: cannot unify branches" error from a onchain view method. Below is the code snippet.
Full error msg: [error] Type Error
sp.TRecord(
locked_balance = sp.TNat,
refundable_balance = sp.TNat,
usable_balance = sp.TNat,
user_balance = sp.TNat) is not sp.TUnit
sp.if: cannot unify branches

```
@sp.onchain_view()
def balance_of(self, params):
    sp.set_type(params, sp.TRecord(owner=sp.TAddress, coin_name=sp.TString))

    sp.if params.coin_name == self.data.native_coin_name:
        sp.result(sp.record(usable_balance = sp.nat(0),
                                locked_balance = self.data.balances[sp.record(address=params.owner, coin_name=params.coin_name)].locked_balance,
                                refundable_balance = self.data.balances[sp.record(address=params.owner, coin_name=params.coin_name)].refundable_balance,
                                user_balance = sp.nat(2)))

    fa2_address = self.data.coins[params.coin_name]
    usable_balance=sp.nat(1)
    sp.if fa2_address != sp.address("tz10000"):
        pass   
    sp.if fa2_address == sp.address("tz10000"):
        pass
    sp.result(sp.record(usable_balance=usable_balance,
                            locked_balance=self.data.balances[sp.record(address=params.owner, coin_name=params.coin_name)].locked_balance,
                            refundable_balance=self.data.balances[sp.record(address=params.owner, coin_name=params.coin_name)].refundable_balance,
                            user_balance=user_balance))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something of the same type (or fail the execution) in the case where the if statement evaluates to false. An untested example:

```
    sp.else:
        // return a default value
        sp.result(sp.record(usable_balance = sp.nat(0),
                                locked_balance = sp.nat(0),
                                refundable_balance = sp.nat(0),
                                user_balance = sp.nat(0)))
        // or just use failwith
        // sp.failwith("error message")
```

Comment: Yeah there is something below if the case fails. I have edited the question above.

Comment: Looks like putting everything below if into else would make sense. And this solve the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the else branch:

```
sp.else:
  sp.failwith("INVALID_COIN_NAME")
```

Michelson is a functional and strongly typed language, every branch must result in the same type or explicitly fail.